# Are the Asian girls in this music video Chinese or Malaysian, and are they singing in Chinese?

Tags: china, malaysia, asia, chinese-language, malay-language

This video: https://youtu.be/BuAULI7PbRw?t=7

They are obviously Asian, and I seem to recognize some of the letters as being Chinese. Also, the song itself seems to be a famous/classic Chinese song which I've heard in other contexts as well.

However, there is also a "Romanized" or "Latinized" text above the Chinese (?) text, which confuses me.

Also, the video description contains a **.my** link, which is the TLD for **Malaysia**.

So, are they Malaysian or Chinese? And if they are Malaysian, why are they singing a Chinese song in Chinese?

Bonus points if you can tell me where and when they recorded the video.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't even close to a travel question.  I am not sure whether there is another stack it would fit on.

Comment: This is off topic. You might like to know that around a quarter of Malaysians are Malaysian Chinese, and I think this should answer your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would probably be better off on https://chinese.stackexchange.com

Comment: That would be 'Chinese language Stack Exchange' and I do not think this question fits as it is.

Comment: They are Malaysian Chinese.

Comment: There is a Chinese language SE and you could check to see if it would be considered on-topic there. Probably their accent could be identified.

Answer (score 2):

The link below the video goes to their Facebook page where it is quite clear the company itself is in Malaysia.  Since [Malaysia's only official language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malay_language) is not related to Chinese, it is quite possible (but impossible to determine) that the girls are part of Malaysia's Chinese minority.  But the video might have been shot in another country and/or with people from another country.

The Romanization you refer to is called "pinyin."  It has been standard in mainland China for decades and is rapidly becoming standard in Taiwan.

But your question really doesn't belong here, since it is not about **Travel**.